# Does skewness multiplied by kurtosis have some intuitive meaning?

Tags: skewness, kurtosis

I understand the individual measures of skewness (how asymmetric a distribution is) and kurtosis (how "large" the tails are in a distribution). For this specific case, I am referring to Fisher Skewness and Pearson Kurtosis:

$$\tilde{\mu}_3 = E\left[\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^3\right]$$

$$\tilde{\mu}_4 = E\left[\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^4\right]$$

I am wondering if multiplying these two quantities together has some logic or intuition to tell you more about the distribution? Say a distribution is very asymmetric (large skew) but has small tails (small kurtosis), then maybe this quantity would tell you that?

Comment: I'd say the biggest problem with this idea would be the loss of information it entails. Let's say A and B are two samples. If A's kurtosis has a similar value to B's skewness, and vice-versa; in this scenario, the result would be similar, despite the samples being different.

Comment: "Say a distribution is very asymmetric (large skew) but has small tails (small kurtosis), then maybe this quantity would tell you that?" You can see this from looking at skewness and kurtosis separately, so why would you want to multiply them?

Comment: Check the relationship between kurtosis and skewness, and some interesting functions might pop up. Not the product, though.